# Date range query failing for MongoDB database of tweets

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to perform a range query for a collection of tweets in a mongo database.  For some reason the following query will work:

```
db.posts.find({'created_at': {$gte:"Fri Nov 25 00:00:00 +0000 2011", $lt:"Fri Nov 25 23:59:59 +0000 2011"}})
```

But the following will not:

```
db.posts.find({'created_at': {$gte:"Thu Nov 24 00:00:00 +0000 2011", $lt:"Fri Nov 25 23:59:59 +0000 2011"}})
```

I'm entering the tweet as a JSON object directly into the database, so this shouldn't be an issue, correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure you are using real Date values, not strings. For example:

```
var from = ISODate("2011-11-24")
var to = ISODate("2011-11-25T23:59:59")
db.posts.find({ created_at : { $gte : from, $lt : to } })
```

Besides making sure your queries are using real Date values, make sure your stored data contains real Date values  also.

Comment: This returned nothing for me.  It is a valid syntax but the result was an empty set....

Comment: If your data has strings instead of real Date values the query isn't going to work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your query is that you are comparing string with data object, which is not working.
if you are using shell, you can write something like this:

```
db.testing.find({
   'date': {
        $lt : new Date(2013,10,1),
        $gte : new Date(2000,10,1)
   }
})
```

which will eventually transform it into this

```
db.testing.find({
   "date" : {
        "$lt" : ISODate("2013-11-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "$gte" : ISODate("2000-11-01T00:00:00Z")
   }
})
```

about [range queries](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/)

about [dates](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dates)