# Date range query for Mongo document field that is an ISOString but not typed Date?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-schema, isodate

Say I have a collection with documents (from JSON) that include a field with date information - as ISOString (but not Date typed). For example:

```
{
  foo: {
    completed: "2015-02-25T12:44:47.335Z"
  }
}
```

How can I perform a date range query on this data? As far as I can tell the field is treated as a String. I'm also using Mongoose. Can I do something in the schema to type this sub-field appropriately?

Comment: You need to be use ISODate format. Please go through - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460160/date-range-query-failing-for-mongodb-database-of-tweets

Comment: I've further clarified the question. The data already has an ISOString as a String. The obvious answer is to preprocess the data before adding to the database. I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting to a `Date` type is best, but you can still perform sorting and range filtering on ISO date strings.

```js
db.test.find({'foo.completed': {
    $gt: '2015-01-25T12:44:47.335Z', 
    $lt: '2015-03-25T12:44:47.335Z'
}})
```

Comment: It actually works. Heh, I actually had similar code in another location and completely forgotten about it. Thanks for the sanity check.

Comment: I am using the exact same query for the same condition but its not working